# what is return error value of mysql_query in C?

Tags: c, mysql

folks, 
from the following code

```
int a = mysql_query(conn,"INSERT into data VALUES (NULL,'tes','aja'));
```

how come i could make sure mysql_query is do the supposed thing, because i've tried wrong sql query and it becomes same return value

from mysql_query function which from file mysql.h:

```
int     STDCALL mysql_query(MYSQL *mysql, const char *q);
```

is there a way to check that string of query is valid and queried properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MySQL reference documentation for mysql_query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-query.html) this should return zero on success and non-zero on failure. Are you sure that it is returning 0 value for an invalid query?

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised that the MySQL database I had to use did not return error on "wrong query". *(The MySQL database is not in my administration)* You do not write what exact problem do you have with you query; what is the problem. I suppose my problem can be similar to your problem.

*(Example table is simplified.)*

My table 'T' with cols 'A' varchar[10] not null, 'B' varchar[10]

```
int a = mysql_query(conn,"INSERT INTO T (B) VALUE ('data')");
```

The problem is that the result is OK, error message is empty and only one warning is present.

Solution is to test not only error but also warnings.

```
if ( mysql_errno( conn ) || mysql_warning_count( conn ) )
  result = 1; //error
else
  result = 0; //OK
```

If you need to display warnings/errors there is my simple sample code:

```
static void display_warnings( MYSQL *conn )
{
  MYSQL_RES *sql_result;
  MYSQL_ROW row;
  if ( ( conn == NULL ) || mysql_query( conn, "SHOW WARNINGS" ) )
  {
    printf( "Can not display list of errors/warnings!\n" );
    return;
  }

  sql_result = mysql_store_result( conn );
  if ( ( sql_result == NULL ) || ( sql_result->row_count == 0 ) )
  {
    printf( "Can not display list of errors/warnings!\n" );
    if ( sql_result )
      mysql_free_result( sql_result );
    return;
  }

  row = mysql_fetch_row( sql_result );
  if ( row == NULL )
  {
    printf( "Can not display list of errors/warnings!\n" );
    mysql_free_result( sql_result );
    return;
  }

  do
  {
    // Format: "message [Type: number]"
    printf( "%s [%s: %s]\n", row[2], row[0], row[1] );
    row = mysql_fetch_row( sql_result );
  } while ( row );
  mysql_free_result( sql_result );
}
```

I need to handle that all given data must be correct and none is missing. Missing data *(according to table definition)* is unacceptable; trimming of data *('ABC12345678' changed to 'ABC1234567')* is also unacceptable. Both these problems are handled only as warning. Therefore I handle all warnings as errors.